# Use of the particle を/に indicating target of an action - animate vs inanimate?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-を

Currently learning Japanese from Rosetta stone, and so far, whenever a verb is acting on something, I've always seen the particle を used - eg:

> 彼{かれ}は本{ほん}**を**読{よ}んでいます。

Now the program has thrown に into the mix - eg:

> 彼{かれ}は奥{おく}さん**に**キスしています。

So my question: is the particle を only for inanimate objects?  In the sentence above, could I use を after 奥{おく}さん since she's the direct object of the action, or is に the only answer because the direct object is an animate being?  Would I ever use に in the other sentence, like 彼{かれ}は本{ほん}**に**読{よ}んでいます?

Or is this just one of those "That's just the way it is, just roll with it" kind of quirks with the language?

Comment: ha, yeah, sorry.  Rosetta Stone tends to clump things together; otoko no ko is written as otokonoko, while otoko no hito is properly spaced.  Reading in hiragana has helped figure things out a bit :)

Comment: Feel free to use hiragana instead!

Comment: How do you write in hiragana? Is there a browser extension for it?

Comment: @Greg You just need Japanese support on your computer.  How to do *that* depends on your OS―you can look up how to do that, and if you have problems, you can ask on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).  The browser will support it fine once you've got your OS set up properly :-)  In the meantime, I edited the question to contain kana (and kanji with furigana), but if you'd like to edit it, please feel free!

Comment: @snailboat Many thanks again.  That's all I need as far as how to type in hiragana; I can easily google for step by step instructions.

As for the post, as long as it's in hiragana/katakana, I can work out any answers people give, and it'll help train my eyes to read it the more often I see it (kanji's still a long way off for me, lol)